# jsp session variable returns null (sometimes)

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I have an already running application. It uses a lot of Ajax requests communicating with JSPs. There are a lot of necessary session variables I have to set, but sometimes for some reason, the session variable I set before returns "null" and I really don't know why.. It works most of the times.
What could cause this?

Thanks in advance,

mh

Example:
In one JSP I set an amount like this..

```
double n=curbal*2;
request.getSession().setAttribute("amount",new Double(n));
```

then I get it with the following in another JSP..

```
Double temp=(Double) request.getSession().getAttribute("amount");
```

There are about 3 minutes between setting the variable and getting it..

Comment: Require more information on this. You need to isolate one specific scenario and post the question.

Comment: +1 for the `(sometimes)` in the title, made me laugh `:)`

Comment: First, have Java codes in a JSP is a bad practice (you should use some taglib). And your code snippets aren't enough for that we can help you

Comment: its a very big project.. and I dont know what to insert?! Nothing else happens with the variable..

Comment: Data in session will not vanish itself. If its the same session then the value must have been removed from session explicitly. Check you code where the value is being removed.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to set a breakpoint at this line :

`request.getSession().setAttribute("amount",new Double(n));`

And see if your attribute is really set when the session variable is null.